# C# wpf listbox not updating from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to get the databinding I need to work with a ListBox.
I've parsed some data from a text file to a `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>` but the data isn't updating in the ListBox.

Here's some information:

The data which is written to from the parser:

```
class MainData
{
    private static ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> groupModelList = new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();
    public static ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> GroupModelList
    {
        get { return groupModelList; }
    }
}
```

What `GroupViewModel` holds (not everything but it's all the same):

```
class GroupViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private GroupModel groupModel;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public GroupViewModel()
    {
        groupModel = new GroupModel();
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return groupModel.name; }
        set
        {
            if (groupModel.name != value)
            {
                groupModel.name = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And what `GroupModel` Holds:

```
class GroupModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the parser adds new items to the `GroupModelView`:

```
if (split[0] == "group")
{
    currentGroup = new GroupViewModel();
    currentGroup.Name = split[1];

    MainData.GroupModelList.Add(currentGroup);
}
```

I created a ListBox in my WPF application with these XAML options:

```
<Window x:Class="SoundManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SoundManager.ViewModels"
    xmlns:vm2="clr-namespace:SoundManager.Code"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="1280">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
    <vm2:MainData x:Key="MainData" />
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Height="484" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="lbFoundItems" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainData}, Path=GroupModelList/Name}" />
```

but for some reason the data isn't updating in the UI (new items aren't added visibly in the UI).
I've been just getting started with the MVVM pattern and databinding and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GroupModelList/Name` is not a valid property path here. Setting it like that does not make the ListBox show the `Name` property of the data items in the `GroupModelList` collection.

You would instead have to set the ListBox's `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainData}, Path=GroupModelList}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

or set the `ItemTemplate` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainData}, Path=GroupModelList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Moreover, the `GroupModelList` property should not be static:

```
class MainData
{
    private ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> groupModelList =
        new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> GroupModelList
    {
        get { return groupModelList; }
    }
}
```

Then you might have `MainData` as a property in your view model, and bind the ListBox like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel},
                               Path=MainData.GroupModelList}" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did solve the problem! So, as a followup. Am I doing this MVVM thing kind of properly? (Judging from what you can see in the question)

Comment: If you would make MainData a property in MainViewModel, as suggested in the answer, I'd say yes.